# How to highlight the searched keyword on results page?

Tags: search

When you search in Magento, on search result page you will see the results with below text for example,

**Search results for 'configure'**

Here my search keyword is **configure**.

How can I highlight the searched keyword on results page ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be found in *app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalogsearch\result.phtml*. So create a local copy of that file in your theme and add some code/CSS to highlight your search term.

The code will look like that:

```
<h1><?php echo ($this->getHeaderText() || $this->getHeaderText() === false) ? $this->getHeaderText() : $this->__("Search results for '%s'", $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getEscapedQueryText()) ?></h1>
```

The search term itself comes from:

```
$this->helper('catalogsearch')->getEscapedQueryText()
```

So you can take that out and add some element around it with a class or id. After that add a style for that class or id, something like:

```
.yourGivenClass {
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

That should be it.

Regards

Comment: The above solution would work only to highlight the searched text. What I want is to highlight the searched text all over my result page.For example if I search **t-shirt** then all the products on search result page having word **t-shirt** in their name or description gets highlighted.

Comment: Well, in that case you have to open the template file and get the name or the description (do you display the description on the search result page at all?) and use a regular expression to search for your seach term in for example the name of the product. If found, replace (preg_replace) the match with `<span class="yourGivenClass">$term</span>`. That should do it.